# What licensing should I include or consider if I am building a program in Python and a range of PyPi libraries?

Tags: licensing, copyright

The program I am building for our production system relies heavily and Python and a few libraries such as pandas, flask, jupyter and pillow. I have observed that the licensing tied to them are mainly BSD3 and MIT. From a license perspective, do I have to bundle all the library licenses and copyrights?

Comment: What does “production” mean? If you aren't giving anyone else a copy of the software, the vast majority of open source licenses imposes no conditions.

Comment: Production in a sense that its deployed internally for own use. So in my case in a corporate setting interacting with different systems and in terms of licensing, a review of legality of usage.

Answer (score 2):

The requirements of copyright licenses only come into play when you provide the code to other legal entities (people or businesses), with the assumption that they get to decide what to do with it.

If the code doesn't leave your company, or if you only give the code to a hosting company with the explicit instruction to run it on a (virtual) server that you otherwise control, then you are not distributing the code and there are no license-related requirements that you have to comply with.

Comment: I think it is important that no other person interacts with the programmes.